# How do I go invisible in Messages (OS X)?

Tags: messages

I am using Messages for OS X and Google Talk. I'd like to be able to go invisible in Messages. How can I do this?

Comment: 280 page views and still no answer :) I searched the same question in the past and it looks it isn't possible to go invisible in Messages/iChat

Comment: @Chiron There's an answer, but it's perhaps not one you or the asker wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get invisibility using Apple's Messages app on OS X. [According to Google, their client also does not support invisible status](http://support.google.com/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162730), so perhaps it's a limitation of their API and only something you can set using their web app. They get to serve you ads when you are on the web, but not on a client so perhaps that was a factor in deciding to code that function in one place over the other.

Apple's Messages app on OS X will set an invisible status for AIM accounts, but not for Google Talk, so it's less like a Messages oversight as an account/API design issue from Google.

Comment: So sorry I didn't accept this. Should've a long time ago :)